# How to create a compiler in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction

Before answering this question, understand that I am not asking how to create my own programming language, I am asking how, using vb.net code, I can create a compiler for a language like vb.net itself. Essentially, the user inputs code, they get a .exe. By NO MEANS do I want to write my own language, as it seems other compiler related questions on here have asked. I also do not want to use the vb.net compiler itself, nor do I wish to duplicate the IDE.

The exact purpose of what I wish to do is rather hard to explain, but all I need is a nudge in the right direction for writing a compiler (from scratch if possible) which can simply take input and create a .exe. I have opened .exe files as plain text before (my own programs) to see if I could derive some meaning from what I assumed would be human readable text, yet I was obviously sorely disappointed to see the random ascii, though it is understandable why this is all I found.

I know that a .exe file is simply lines of code, being parsed by the computer it is on, but my question here really boils down to this: What code makes up a .exe? How could I go about making one in a plain text editor if I wanted to? (No, I do not want to do that, but if I understand the process my goals will be much easier to achieve.) What makes an executable file an executable file? Where does the logic of the code fit in?

This is intended to be a programming question as opposed to a computer question, which is why I did not post it on SuperUser. I know plenty of information about the System.IO namespace, so I know how to create a file and write to it, I simply do not know what exactly I would be placing inside this file to get it to work as an executable file.

I am sorry if this question is "confusing", "dumb", or "obvious", but I have not been able to find any information regarding the actual contents of an executable file anywhere.

[One of my google searches](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS338US338&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what+makes+up+an+executable+file)

[Something that looked promising](http://www.ehow.com/how_2315200_make-exe-files-using-notepad.html)

EDIT: The second link here, while it looked good, was an utter fail. I am not going to waste hours of my time hitting keys and recording the results. "Use the "Alt" and the 3-digit combinations to create symbols that do not appear on the keyboard but that you need in the program." (step 4) How the heck do I know what symbols I need???

Thank you very much for your help, and my apologies if this question is a nooby or "bad" one.

To sum this up simply: I want to create a program in vb.net that can compile code in a particular language to a single executable file. What methods exist that can allow me to do this, and if there are none, how can I go about writing my own from scratch?

Comment: I think you vastly underestimate the complexity of compilers.  There are entire courses in college over this single topic.

Comment: Hence my apologies if this was a dumb question. Clearly those were not without warrant. I did google it, as you can see, and I was not expecting a small answer.

Comment: According to Joel, writing a compiler is two months work for a talented person who read the dragon book: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01b.html

Comment: It's definitely a nooby question, but I wouldn't call it a bad one.  Clearly you know nothing of what you're asking about, and have no idea what it entails, but you're not going to find out about that without asking somebody.  BTW, the second link is indeed useless, and your question about what symbols you need is dead on:  it's like enrolling in a sonnet-writing course and being taught how to touch-type.

Comment: Yep, I know absolutely nothing about this, and it is definitely nooby. And yeah, that second link failed.

Comment: People overestimate how hard it is to write a compiler. You don't need a degree, you dont need the dragon book. You just need to start small, use existing tools like Antlr, and a bit of hard work. You can have a trivial interpreter in a few days, and slowly build it up. That said, its not clear how good a coder you are. If you're only starting to code, this might not be the best first project.

Comment: I think Mono has got a vb.net compiler written in vb.net somewhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking is a pretty complex question. Sure, at its core it seems pretty basic:

1. Interpret the code itself
2. Write out the interpreted code

but each of those steps can be pretty intense. Step 1 should be somewhat achievable with some time and a LOT of elbow grease - you need to parse the code into a number of control statements based upon the specification of the language. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing for more information on this step. In essence you're converting the typed code into a common format that represents the functionality you want.

Once you've parsed the code, the next step would be to take that parsed code and convert it into machine-runnable code (typically assembly, though with VB.NET you can write Microsoft Intermediate Language code as the output and then run it in the CLR). This is what will actually create the executable file in a manner that lets the computer run the program.

Unfortunately, the best advice for solving this problem is to either:

1. Go purchase several books on a programming language, machine code, assembly language, compilers, and so on, then spend several months or years reading and experimenting until the knowledge you gain from the books results in your writing a successful compiler.
2. Enroll in a computer science program at a local university. Writing compilers and programming languages are usually covered at a rudimentary level during the second or third year of a BS in computer science, and then in much more depth at a graduate level.

Good luck!

EDIT: If all you're looking for is a way to write code and then write a way to execute it, you might try looking at writing an interpreter for one of the scripting languages that already exist - Ruby, Python, Lua, etc.

Comment: Look at my edit about the second link, that is why I said it looked promising, yet in reality it made no sense. I don't intend on specifically getting a degree just so I can make a compiler, or purchase any books on the subject. This seems really more complex than it should be lol...

Comment: Saw the edit after I posted - honestly that link is a travesty :)

True, at its core all you're doing is taking a certain pattern of text and converting it into a certain pattern of 1s and 0s - if you define it that way, then yeah it's definitely easy. Of course, if we follow that path:

- Basketball is really just putting the ball in the hoop
- Building a house is really just combining wood and nails
- Speaking a foreign language is really just memorization

Some people spend years learning to write compilers - it's deceptively complex :)

Comment: I have become convinced at this point that it would nearly be simpler for me to write my own language entirely, and simply write all logic myself as a parser. Of course, this is also ridiculous, as I have no need for an entirely new language (though I did once attempt to write a Lolcode parser in vb.net, it is the only language that uses "OH NOES" as an exception handler.

Comment: @Cyclone:  It would not be simpler for you to write your own language, since the complexity is in compiling anything.  Writing any sort of compiler is going to be a massive learning experience for you and a tremendous amount of work, and getting a computer science degree may well be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @Cyclone: "This seems really more complex than it should be..."  How simple do you think it *should* it be to translate human-understandable text into a binary something that can be mashed by a series of electronic logic gates to produce some result that's still human-sensible?

Comment: I really dislike this answer. It looks like its trying to make it seem really difficult. You dont explain what an interpreter is; your link to parsing discusses the theory of it, instead of linking to a parser generator; and the end just says "you aren't good enough, get a degree, or at least a book". Really, a travesty of an answer. -1.

Answer (score 4):

```
Process.Start(String.Format("vbc.exe {0}", sourceFilePath))
```

Comment: "how can I go about writing my own from scratch?" I cannot assume the user has the vb ide installed on their computer.

Comment: You don't need the IDE to get the compiler...only the SDK which is free to download.

Comment: @Cyclone - In all seriousness, re-writing a VB.NET compiler in VB.NET is a massive undertaking and not one that I (or, I'm guessing, anybody else here would want to undertake). Using the freely distributable .NET SDK would be MUCH easier.

Comment: K, can I have a link? Also, this is for vb.net correct? With the string "sourceFilePath", what should be the contents of the source file? This is vb.net, not vb6, so a vbscript file is not a part of this at all, and a vbscript file is the only file I could think of that would be compilable into it as a single file.

Comment: @Cyclone - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en

Comment: k, now what goes into the file at sourceFilePath?

Comment: The path to the .vb files you want to compile into the .exe ...but if you're going this route, don't even worry about writing the app. Just call the compiler directly...

Comment: There is the issue though, I do not want it to compile a normal project though....thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**The Visual Basic .NET compiler is shipped for free as part of the .NET Framework** - you don't even need the SDK or Express Editions. The compiler for VB (and C#) is located at **c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework[version]\vbc.exe** (or csc.exe for C#). Therefore, any computer which can run a VB.NET program can compile one. The .NET **Framework also  includes the System.CodeDom namespace** which provides a way from within a program to compile a program, either from a document model or from a string (or file) into a .NET assembly (.exe or .dll) and generate code in both VB and C#.

Regards,

**Anthony D. Green** | Program Manager | **Visual Basic Compiler**

Comment: Yes, I have found the necessary code in the namespace you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [one book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590591348) that explains it all at a very basic level. Including sample code that you can get working in a matter of hours.

As with many programming endevors, it will take you many months of study to accomplish what you want. Good luck!!

Comment: Ill add that to my shopping cart and see if I can find any cheaper solutions till then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Let me start by saying this is totally doable. Ignore the naysayers.

OK, so it seems you bit off more than you could chew here. I would suggest slightly re-evaluating your goal. It seems that you want to learn how compilers work, and writing a VB.net compiler is your project to get started.

Try instead to write an interpreter, which is a much smaller and simpler task. Here's how you do it:

- Write a parser for a very very small language, maybe only supporting assignment statements. Use a parser toolkit, like [Antlr](http://www.antlr2.org/doc/csharp-runtime.html). This will build an AST ("abstract syntax tree" - ie a few classes or objects representing the program's syntax, without the crap like semi-colons, as a tree), which will look something like this:

[image]

- then you go through the AST, and just execute it. Google for "AST walker". So for the assignment `x = 5`, create a hashtable entry for 'x', assign 5 to it, then move on to the next statement.
- keep adding features as you go.

Once you've got the full language, you'll probably have learned enough on the way to understand the compiler books. Don't use the dragon book, try Appel's book instead, or Cooper/Torczon. There are online books if you prefer, I've never tried them.

When you go to write the compiler, you'll just be changing the bit that executes the AST into one which generates assembly (or C if you prefer) which will do the same action when it's run.

I'll grant that it seems daunting, but if you stick to a something simple to start, you'll get something working in a few days at most. In a few months, you'll have built it up to something like what you're looking for. Good luck.

#### To the final part of your question:

It seems that you don't know how executables are made from code. People haven't messed with hex in their compilers since the 80s, and hopefully not much even then.
Basically, after parsing the code, you go through a series of steps which make the code progressively simpler. At the end of that, you have something that is quite close to assembly. You then generate assembly, and the *assembler* and *linker* conspire to make it into an executable.

Answer (score 1):

You create a compiler for vb.net the same way you create any other compiler. You need a lexer/parser. Entire books have been written on this topic, the most famous probably being [The Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science)).

To provide a definitive answer: No, you cannot create a decent compiler that will generate an executable file using Notepad. You need a compiler to convert from human-readable text into the machine language (assembly or IL) that a linker or interpreter can then execute.

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided? That should be enough to get you to scrap the idea of writing it in Notepad...

Comment: I never intended to write an executable in notepad?

Comment: Ah... I guess this part of your original post confused me: "How could I go about making one in a plain text editor if I wanted to?"

Comment: I was asking more about the actual structure of the .exe file itself than going out and MAKING one in notepad.

Comment: It's binary machine code that contains instructions for the CPU to execute, regardless of what language it's written in. (OK, not quite true - if you're writing in VB script, for example, it's text that the VB script runtime compiles into something it interprets and turns into machine code. However, you asked about .EXE files.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking out my tutorial at http://www.icemanind.com

It is a tutorial on creating your own virtual machine and assembler, written in 100% C#.

Answer (score 0):

Cyclone, I'm wondering exactly what are you trying to achieve? You say "the exact purpose of what I wish to do is rather hard to explain" and "essentially, the user inputs code, they get a .exe".

If you just want the user to be able to enter code and then execute it, you might consider an existing scripting language. [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6(VS.85).aspx) is built into Windows and the language is fairly similar to VB.Net, or there are various excellent free languages you can download like [Python](http://www.python.org/).

If the user really needs to be able to create a .exe - I think it's likely scripting might do - then why not use an existing free compiler like [FreeBasic](http://www.freebasic.net/index.php/download), or even [Visual Basic.Net Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VB/).

Answer (score 0):

I am making a tutorial for that in my website, http://dgblogs.weebly.com. It is written with C# and you can create your own computer programming language!

You will never see this syntax in my tutorials:

```
Console.Readline();
```

My website is currently offline by now so, GOOD LUCK!

Thanks,
DgBlogs

Answer (score 0):

Im quite shocked that this question was never fully answered ; Recently i came across some tutorials on the subject of developing a programming language from scratch https://www.youtube.com/c/DmitrySoshnikov-education/playlists
Although the person uses Java Script the technique used for creating the tokenizer and the parser to consume the output from the tokenizer producing the AST for the transcribed language which i would consider to be GOLD! ...
Another tutorial or person https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSq9OFrD2Q3DasoOa54Vm9Mr8CATyTbLF
Toby Ho! Has also produce various methods using the Nearly parser (plugin) to build a language much easier but not a Pure code coder like myself(does not like extensions to do the work which i can do myself)....
https://github.com/spydaz/SpydazWeb-AI-_Emulators

I was able to do some different experiments designing a stack machine (runs mini assembly language). for my "Toy" Programming language(basic) could be executed on. (the VM) - Using Visual Basic(My personal Lang - I think in VB)

Since revisiting the tutorials ;
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRAdsfhKI4OWNOSfS7EUu5GRAVmze1t2y
Immo Landwerth! Had a few more experiments This time with C#
A bit more Spaghetti to mull over; but actually revealing (after knowing a lot more);

Yes IT is possible to design a Compiler / VM with VB.net Quite easily ... without external tools .

For myself as an AI developer (CONVERSATIONAL AI / NLP)  i was interested in building a compiler for the English language if it would be possible to use the technique for parsing syntax trees and building syntax trees from text using the Tokenizer/Parser to AST Method , as well as designing the transpiler to allow for the syntax tree to be used for translation to other languages. as with today's programming languages merely being a Higher lever language interfacing with a low level(VM) language. in-fact we should be developing more natural language - programming languages and dispelling the more cryptic languages such as C# (Lol) and Java and Go and the like (so many brackets and semi colons / tabs etc - truly not needed!) and that is to say that we programmers still think in code! the journey  as a AI developer crosses many domains. forces many off topic research pathways .. So Again a big YES! and we Still could say that ANy programming language can be used to create another programming language it just depends on which language you "THINK IN" .... hence not having too many languages using (i understand most programming languages - but i will always think in VB)...

Answer (score 0):

The Small Visual Basic programming language is fully written in VB .NET and its source code is published here:
https://github.com/VBAndCs/sVB-Small-Visual-Basic
It shows you how to create a small compiler with a code editor, language services and a form designer.